# python indexing and assign by row ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, indexing

Something is wrong in my script and I found the error, but I'm completely stuck.

there is array b which contains two elements:

```
b = np.zeros ((1,2))

b[0,0] = 272
b[0,1] = 1578
```

I want to check if there are elements in the second columns, greater than a value, and if so, assign that value a zero.

the command

```
b[ b[:,1] >= 1000 ] = 0
```

changes both elements to 0 instead of `b[0,1]`

what am I missing?

thanks in advance

C

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you only want to set the second column to zero (if its value is >1000)? I extended your example to have at least two rows, but just tested it to work also with one:

```
b = np.array([[123, 456],
              [789, 101112]])
mask = b[:,1] > 1000
b[mask,1] = 0

print b
```

I defined `mask` to explain it better - you can substitute it in.
`mask` is then a boolean vector with one element for each row, in this case `[False, True]`. In the last step, that `mask` is used to mask out the selected rows and assign zero to the first column element.

Comment: yes, I want to set the element in the second column to zero, if that element is greater than a value, e.g. greather than 1000

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could loop over b ?

```
b_rows = 1 #number of your rows
for i in range(b_rows):
   if b[i,1] >= 1000:
      b[i,1]=0
```